ASP.NET Core 8 Identity Authorize with Cookies
How to configure auth mechanism to work with Cookies in ASP.NET Core 8 Web API? I'm able to login with use of built-in method /login generated by .AddIdentityApiEndpoints. If I now use the returned Bearer token, everything works just fine.
I'd like to use Cookies instead (returned from /login?useCookies=true)
Here is my Program.cs setup
using Backend.Api.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

// SQL
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme);

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapIdentityApi<IdentityUser>();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

The basic Cookies setup:
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});


Change your code to:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)
    .AddIdentityCookies();

builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder();

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddApiEndpoints();

Reference:What’s new with identity in .NET 8
Then whole working configuration:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)
    .AddIdentityCookies();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder();
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddApiEndpoints();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication(); 
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapIdentityApi<IdentityUser>();

app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", (HttpContext httpContext) =>
{
    var forecast = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index =>
        new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
        })
        .ToArray();
    return forecast;
})
.WithName("GetWeatherForecast")
.RequireAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapRazorPages();


app.Run();


There must be something missing. If I call GET /weatherforecast without any Cookies, I still get the 200 response.

Sorry my bad, looks like it is working! Will experiment a bit more

I still get the 200 response  have you add .RequireAuthorization() or [Authorize] attribute  to your endpoint? It works fine in my side and it will get 401 if i do not login with cookie.

Ok, fine. Glad my answer helped you.

I thought something like this:
 builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        }).AddIdentityCookies();


This doesn't seems to be right approach.
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Scheme already exists: Identity.Application'
